# Which is the best way to make automated backups?

Tags: odoo

I'm using openERP v6.1 and I wanted to know which is the best alternative to make automated backups of the DB (let's say daily backups)

The Backup option in the web UI in Manage Databases it's great to restore and create the DB in one step. Of course it has to be done manually. Is there any way to automatize this process and get as results the same kind of backups? (I'm not sure what kind of file it exports as *.dump)

I tried doing pg_dump but I cannot import that file (I tried the raw sql text and gziped) from the web UI, of course must be different formats. And I have some issues trying to import a pg_dump backup to postgres with psql. I can restore the backup but then when access the site in the web, I saw an openERP empty

Any thoughts about best practices to do this?

Comment: I observed the same issue. When I upgraded from PostgreSQL 9.1 to 9.2, I dumped the databases from 9.1 and restored them to 9.2. For 9.2, OpenERP did not recognize those databases.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you have access to the server running OpenERP, I recommend using pg_dump (with the "custom" format) via a system level cron task.

Rationale:

- you'll get finer control over your backup, including if necessary continuous archiving and point in time recovery (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup.html)
- you won't depend on OpenERP being up and running for the backups to happen. Especially, OpenERP is known for *not* running its scheduled tasks after restart until a first connection is made to the server, which in some case can be a real pain.

Regarding your "issues trying to import a pg_dump backup to postgres with psql. I can restore the backup but then when access the site in the web, I saw an openERP empty", you'll have to tell us a bit more about the commands you used. I've never had any issues using pg_dump / pg_restore with my OpenERP databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a python script which will back up your DB into particular Directory.
and then make a cron job which causes your python script to execute daily.

You can also download module from apps.openerp.com:
http://apps.openerp.com/addon/1759

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution developed to make automated backups of one OpenERP7 database of interest deployed on a Synology box running DSM5.2. This solution replicates the way in which a database is backed up manually using the OpenERP user interface. In order to implement the solution it is necessary to use SSH to gain access to the Synology NAS file system. Parameters can be adjusted to suit the needs of the end user.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Synology OpenERP database backup utiliy. Specify variable information below.
# Run at /etc/crontab at the desired interval.
DIR=/volume1/OpenERP_Backup/
DATESTAMP=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")                                           
DB_USER=OPENERP7                                                        
DATABASE=Demo

# create backup dir if it does not exist                        
mkdir -p ${DIR}

# remove all backups except the $KEEP latest                    
KEEP=7                                                          
BACKUPS=`find ${DIR} -name "${DATABASE}_*.dump" | wc -l | sed 's/\ //g'`
while [ $BACKUPS -ge $KEEP ]                                            
 do                                                                      
  ls -tr1 ${DIR}${DATABASE}_*.dump | head -n 1 | xargs rm -f            
  BACKUPS=`expr $BACKUPS - 1`                                         
done

# dump the database in a file                                       
FILENAME=${DIR}${DATABASE}_${DATESTAMP}.dump                        
/usr/syno/pgsql/bin/pg_dump --format=c --no-owner --username=${DB_USER} 
--file=${FILENAME} ${DATABASE}

#Development Notes
#Notes on how OpenERP handles backup & restore: 
#For backup
#pg_dump --format=c --no-owner --username=<> --host=<> --port=<> <dbname>
#For restore:
#pg_restore --no-owner --dbname=<> 

#Notes on how Synology DSM handles crontab jobs:
#Run script by assigning job to the crontab. Crontab on Synology NAS can
be found at:
#/etc/crontab 
#crontab entry would look something like the following:
#10  1  *   *   *   root    sh /volume1/OpenERP_Backup/backup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "issues trying to import a pg_dump backup to postgres with psql. I can restore the backup but then when access the site in the web, I saw an openERP empty"

You have to create DB and run psql on behalf of openerp postgres user.

Answer (score 0):

For Creating automatic backup of postgresql database

1. Create one folder under home Directry

   ```
   mkdir database_backup
   ```

2.Create new file

```
   nano pg-backup.sh
```

write this code inside that file

```
#enable this option, if you are creating hourly backup
if [ ! -d "$2/`date +%F-%H`" ]; then
mkdir $2/`date +%F-%H`
pg_dump $1 > $2/`date +%F-%H`/$1.sql
else
echo "Do not run this script manually !"
fi

#enable this option, if you are creating daily backup
if [ ! -d "$2/`date +%F`" ]; then
mkdir $2/`date +%F`
pg_dump $1 > $2/`date +%F`/$1.sql
else
echo "Do not run this script manually !"
fi
```

3. Now  run this command

   ```
   chmod 755 pg_backup.sh
   ```

Now run this command for hourlly backup

```
    sudo crontab -e
```

add this line

```
@hourly /home/openerp/database_backup/pg_backup.sh database_name /home/openerp/database_backup/
```

For creating daily backup

You can create a daily backups using below commands

```
    sudo crontab -e
```

Add below lines to that edited file and save it.

```
     @daily /home/openerp/database_backup/pg_backup.sh database_name /home/openerp/database_backup/
```

for performing this action you should ned to create root user under postgresql database 
Now if you want to restore your database intoo openerp

login with postgres user then run this command

```
psql -username <openerp_database_user> -dbname <New_database_name> -f <path_of_backuped_.sql_file>
```